# How to send MMS in J2ME?

Tags: java-me, mms

How to send MMS in J2ME?

Comment: Instead of asking the same question 3 different ways, why not just edit your second one to include the language and the other information you were asked for?

Comment: @Brandon - It looks like a (very) slightly different question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [JSR 205](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=205).

Here's a [sample code](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/sending-and-recieving-mms-on-j2me-devices-4.html) at Java Tips.

Obviously the handset and service provider have to support MMS...

Last link, a [more descriptive piece](http://java.sys-con.com/node/44695) on J2ME MMS.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your understanding

I hoped that I could vote up for you but it requires 15 reputation :)

Answer (score 2):

Martin Clayton's answer is correct except it's actually [JSR 205](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=205) you need for MMS.

Answer (score 0):

As with all good things in Java Mobile remember to test on your target handsets, some over achieving device manufacturers have limited the payload to a max size of 32kb, which you might find tricky if you are sending images or video